# Store time into table

Tags: mysql

I need to populate my table with time values. The columns that will contain these values are type: `TIME`.

This type expects data in the following format: HH:MM:SS and I have values like ***830*** for *8:30 AM*, ***2300*** for *11:00 PM* and ***0*** for midnight. Do I need to pad the values to have 6 digits before inserting them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do LPAD and can use below query for selecting the correct time format.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('2359', '%H%i'), '%h:%i %p');
```